# How to move from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am stuck in a situation where I have to move from recycler view fragment to an activity but doesn't find a working solution for that.please help
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more info? To move means to open Activity?

Comment: Yes to open activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just need a Context instance to open any `Activity`:
`context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class)`

I assume you are asking about opening new `Activity` depending on which `RecyclerView` item was clicked. In that case, you should add `View.OnClickListener` to the `ViewHolder`.

The easiest way is to handle click inside `ViewHolder`. `Context` instance is accessible from any `View` using the `View.getContext()` method. However, I prefer to delegate click back to Fragment/Activity and then open a new screen from there. Check out the sample here: https://github.com/IvanShafran/abbyy-mobile-school-2019/tree/master/RecyclerViewSample